# Debugging on STM32F103

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f10x

I have been on this for about two days now and I'm so frustrated already I don't know what I'm not getting right. I want to be able to use the stm link utility with my stm32f103c8t6 so that I can use the print function in the mcu. I have the stm link v2 mini, and I know that the SWO pin on the board is responsible for send debugging data out of the mcu, what I want to know now is which pin on the stm link v2 mini will I have to connect the SWO to? Pls any idea will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The ST Link *Mini* V2 (not an official ST part) does not have SWO support.
It only has SWDIO and SWDCLK pins.

For the ST Link V2 it should be pin 13, JTAG TDI/SWO.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will go get the official one then

Comment: While that is true, either a mailbox approach as implemented in some open source tools or a serial UART beside the debug channel can still work.